# How to create an object of a class defined as a separate file in java?

Tags: java, class

Following is a file that I have created as token.java

```
public class token{
            String type;
            String value;
            public token(String type,String value)
            {
                this.type=type;
                this.value=value;
            }
            public String str()
            {
                return "Token("+this.type+" , "+this.value+")";
            }
        }
```

Following is the file saved as index.java having main function and creating the object for the above class.

```
public class index{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        token obj=new token("integer","3");
        System.out.println(obj.str());
    }
}
```

Both classes are present in the same folder and when I run the file index.java, it shows the following error:

root@SAMBHAV:/Compiler/Pascal_compiler# java index.java

index.java:4: error: cannot find symbol

```
    token obj=new token("integer","3");

    ^
```

symbol:   class token

location: class index

index.java:4: error: cannot find symbol

```
    token obj=new token("integer","3");
                  ^
```

symbol:   class token

location: class index

2 errors

error: compilation failed

I am using VS CODE as editor and running the files on the terminal using java file_name.java command

Comment: While we're at the subject, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase, and class names in PascalCase.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? In case of a recent one, then your program can be run if the code exists within a single file. Otherwise, you'll need to compile it using `javac`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps below:-

1. Compile the file token.java as [javac token.java]. Verify that a class file token.class gets generated.
2. Compile the file index.java as [javac index.java]. Verify that a class file index.class gets generated.
3. Run the class file index.class as [java index].

Let me know if it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can only run Java prgrams from source with `java filename.java` when all code of the program is in single file. As you can see the JEP is titled [Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330). If you want to have a multi-file (class) program, you have to compile it to bytecode, and only then run it. So, in your case:

```
javac index.java token.java
```

and then:

```
java index
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any package name provided on top of your java files, remove it from both java files and compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile all the java file and then run it:

```
javac token.java index.java
java index
```

The command  `java fileName.java` is used only to execute single file program